# Launcher is invisible but still useful

Tags: 12.04, unity, launcher, icons

[image]

I am using Ubuntu 12.04.  The left launcher is totally invisible but I can still click on and use the icons provided I know where they are (you can see the white tick marks on the left boarder of the screen-shot where I have some things open).  Not impossible but very inconvenient. How can I work around this glitch?

Comment: Does the issue persist when you log out and back in?

Comment: Yes I logged out. I restarted my machine. I restarted unity as well

Comment: Could you please try to [reset the Unity configuration](/a/77789/175814) (move the directories instead of *re*moving them or create back-ups if you want)? Does that help?

Comment: @David Foerster still nothing. would there be any log that would be helpful?

Comment: I can't think of any. Can you try to reproduce this in a new user account? If you don't have temporary guest accounts enabled create a new regular user account the system settings and remove it again after you're done.