# Ubuntu 12.04 launcher doesn't show icons anymore, but they still work

Tags: 12.04, unity, launcher, icons

I have the exact same problem as this one : 
[Launcher is invisible but still useful](https://askubuntu.com/questions/847727/launcher-is-invisible-but-still-useful)

Long story short : Icons on the launchers have become invisible, but they still function. All users are affected, and so is the guest account. The commands

```
unity --reset-icons
unity --reset
```

have no effects but spit warnings and errors. Seems like Compiz is involved and malfunctioning.

Icons do pops up when Unity 2D is chosen at login.

How can I solve this ?

Comment: May be a problem with opacity?

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue I've had on two system installations in recent months that were, to say the least, Frankenstein's monster builds in which I was attempting to put new life into older systems.

On two separate x86 machines, the only flavor of Ubuntu that would both install and play nice with the NVIDIA drivers was Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (i386, obviously).  After a fresh installation of Ubuntu, but prior to activating the NVIDIA driver, icons displayed perfectly fine in the Unity Launcher.  In both machines, the legacy-304 NVIDIA driver was used in tandem with old GeForce 6200 cards (one AGP, one PCI). After activating the NVIDIA driver and restarting the system, all icons in the Unity Launcher would now be invisible.  The icons were still there, functional, and mouse-over displayed which icons were which, but the icons couldn't be seen.

After much hunting and no luck, I found a thread in which a person having the exact same issue (after NVIDIA driver activation, icons vanish but still function) was able to solve it by forcing Ubuntu into 2D, aka, Unity 2D, aka, Unity low-graphics mode.

Here's how to do it:

When Ubuntu first boots and brings up the login screen, there is a small round Ubuntu dash icon located within the login dialogue box directly to the right of your username that will allow you to select the session type.  Click it, and it will give you the options of "Ubuntu" or "Ubuntu 2D".  Select "Ubuntu 2D" and login.

If all goes well, your icons should display.  This might also restore the desktop defaults, so be prepared to redo any personalized touches, such as adding or removing applications from the launcher.  This is a little annoying, but hey, at least you can see the icons again.

One of the systems had auto-login enabled, which bypassed the login screen.  If your system has auto-login enabled, you'll first need to disable it (System Settings --> User Accounts) to see whether or not using an Ubuntu 2D session will fix the invisible icon problem for you.

I can confirm this solution worked on both systems, but I must stress both instances involved fresh installations of Ubuntu 12.04 LTS i386, had NVIDIA GeForce 6200 cards, and required legacy version-304 of NVIDIA's recommended proprietary driver.  Attempting to use Ubuntu 14.04 or 16.04 would always cause a login screen loop (get to the login screen, try to login, desktop fails to load, kicked back to the login screen) after installing the video card drivers on both systems.  I have not attempted to upgrade these two systems to newer versions to see if the "2D Session" fix also prevents the login screen loop in 14.04 and/or 16.04.

If this solution DOES WORK for you, you're happy with Ubuntu 2D (I don't really see much difference in appearance and the slower machine's desktop is now far more responsive), and you want to make Ubuntu default to a 2D session whenever you login, all you need to do is make one small change to `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` with root privileges.  Open a command line terminal, and enter:

```
sudo pico /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

You can also use `nano`. Whichever editor floats your boat.  Edit this line:

```
user-session=ubuntu
```

to read:

```
user-session=ubuntu-2d
```

That's it!  Three little characters.  Save, exit, and restart.  Ubuntu should now start a 2D session by default with all your icons displaying properly whenever the system boots.